# Backbone.js Router and back button check

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Basically, I am trying to check if the previous page on every route was equal to one specific page on my site. If it is, then I want to keep the person on that view, otherwise, they can proceed to the other view.

Is there a way in a Backbone.js router, to fire off a global event that will fire before the route callback is executed?

Or, is there a way to have a catch all route that does some checking then forwards to the appropriate route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think overridding `Backbone.History.navigate` and only invoking the superclass method conditionally might work. You could also add an additional event handler for `window.hashChange` and `window.pushState` events wired up before the backbone history, and prevent the default propagation of those events if your criteria match.